# Castle logging facility for log4net with a fluent log4net configuration

Tags: c#, log4net, castle-windsor, castle

I have a fluent `log4net` configuration.It is in a class called `log4netConfigSetup.cs`. In my Castle installer class, when you add a logging facility like the example shown below it searches for the configuration in `app.config`:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());
}
```

How can I make it look for the fluent config class I have instead of the config file or xml file for the `log4net` configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by implementing [ILoggerFactory](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/src/Castle.Core/Core/Logging/ILoggerFactory.cs), like this partial example: you would need to implement all the parts of the ILogger interface you want to use.

```
using System;
using Castle.Core.Logging;
using Castle.Facilities.Logging;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using log4net;

namespace Castle_Log4Net
{
    public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, 
                            IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>
                    (f => f.LogUsing<Log4NetLoggingFactory>());
        }
    }

    public class Log4NetLoggingFactory : Castle.Core.Logging.ILoggerFactory
    {
        static Log4NetLoggingFactory()
        {
            // here you configure log4net from log4netConfigSetup.cs
        }

        public ILogger Create(Type type)
        {
            return new Log4NetLogger(type);
        }

        public ILogger Create(string name)
        {
            return new Log4NetLogger(name);
        }

        public ILogger Create(Type type, LoggerLevel level)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ILogger Create(string name, LoggerLevel level)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Log4NetLogger : Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger
    {
        private readonly ILog logger;

        public Log4NetLogger(Type type)
        {
            this.logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
        }

        public Log4NetLogger(string name)
        {
            this.logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        }

        public ILogger CreateChildLogger(string loggerName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Debug(string message)
        {
            logger.Debug(message);
        }

        public void Debug(Func<string> messageFactory)
        {
            logger.Debug(messageFactory.Invoke());
        }

        public void Debug(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Debug(message, exception);
        }

        public void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DebugFormat(Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DebugFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DebugFormat(Exception exception, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Error(Func<string> messageFactory)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Error(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ErrorFormat(Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ErrorFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ErrorFormat(Exception exception, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Fatal(Func<string> messageFactory)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Fatal(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void FatalFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void FatalFormat(Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void FatalFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void FatalFormat(Exception exception, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Info(Func<string> messageFactory)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Info(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void InfoFormat(Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void InfoFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void InfoFormat(Exception exception, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Warn(Func<string> messageFactory)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Warn(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WarnFormat(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WarnFormat(Exception exception, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WarnFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WarnFormat(Exception exception, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsDebugEnabled { get; private set; }
        public bool IsErrorEnabled { get; private set; }
        public bool IsFatalEnabled { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInfoEnabled { get; private set; }
        public bool IsWarnEnabled { get; private set; }
    }
}
```